# Disable form controls only not control box etc

Tags: c#

I have this bit of code and it does work but it disables everything on the form including the close button. However Is there anyway to modify it to just disable form controls like textboxs and all. I didn't release the control box was thought of as a control?.

```
public void DisableControls(Control con)
{
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            DisableControls(c);
        }
        con.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void EnableControls(Control con)
    {
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Enabled = true;
            EnableControls(con.Parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over the Controls collection, it's normal that you're disabling all the controls on your form.

A possible solution would be:

```
// This will only disable all the textboxs
public void DisableControls(Control con)
{
    foreach (TextBox c in con.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        c.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

If some TextBoxs are inside another control (like a GroupBox), something like this would work:

```
public void DisableControls(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
    {
        DisableControls(c);
    }

    // This can also be used to disable other types of controls
    if (con is TextBox) con.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Was typing it out

Comment: The only thing I'd add is this is just specific to TextBox's.  Works for TextBox's, but if you want to just focus on a specific section of controls just group them.  Put the controls in question in a some kind of container and just disable the container.  This way it targets all.  This is great though.

Comment: Thanks very much to both you I guess I can just change the type ie if its a mask box or such

Comment: I agree with Dylan's note.